# How to stop a while loop containing two inherited for loops

Tags: python, datetime, time, timeout

```
import time
stop_time = time.time() + 5 #5 seconds
while time.time() < stop_time:
    for i in range(1000000):
        print(i)
        for x in range(654165):
            print(x)
```

How to stop this loop after 5 seconds?

Comment: Maybe try adding `if time.time() >= stop_time: break` in the `for` loops.

Comment: Yes, this is the best method which works. Implemented. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use the perf_counter() method:

```
import time

while time.perf_counter() <= 5:
    for i in range(1000000):
        if time.perf_counter() <= 5:
            print(i)
            for x in range(654165):
                if time.perf_counter() <= 5:
                    print(x)
```

Comment: Thanks for the valuable suggestion. I don't think the execution occurs. Also I am using Python 3.7.4 (64 bit).